# Get Layer info when hover the map in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I have added a Geojson layer to a base map in Leaflet. I used the following event to get the Map data as well as Layer data:

```
map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

it gave me the following log:

[image]

I could not find anything regarding the Geojson layer when I hover it (Nothing in the *target* about the layer).

Does anyone has any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code to get the Geojson layer information:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",....

       onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
           layer.on('mousemove', function (event) {
                console.log(event);
           });
       }
});
```

Comment: Please add clarification, or even better a working example, as this does not look related to the OPs question based on the data you have presented.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `map` variable to get an info about the layers etc.

Actually when you create your layer it seems that it is stored also in a variable so that you can access it.

```
var map = L.map(...);
var geoLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(map);
geoLayer.addData(geojsonFeature);

map.on('mousemove', function(event) {
  console.log(event, geoLayer, map);
});
```

Comment: I need the information of the feature that the mouse hovering over. This code just gives us the whole features data that exist in the _geoLayer_.

Comment: Then you need to use mouse handler on each object instead of map itself

Comment: Correct, I used `layer.on('mousemove', function (event)...` inside the `onEachFeature` option.